# Hide Toast from included libbrary

Tags: android, toast

I am using a library project in my android application. when i am opening my app it shows a toast on screen. i want to disable / hide / cancel the toast that was generated in library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Toast` from your library `java` file.

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your library classes and remove the code that displays `Toast`.As simple as that